# .NET 6 Blazor Server side hangs on authenticating user

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Blazor server side which gets all data from an API; the only connection to a SQL Server is to use Identity authentication with individual user accounts.

It works ok in the development environment but when deployed to IIS, it hangs when trying to access the database, which is hosted on the same server.

I can't get the exact error since the warning thrown says:

> Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information
> about the error that occurred. The Development environment shouldn't
> be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying
> sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local
> debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the
> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and
> restarting the app.

Anything I tried to set production `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `development` - from other posts unfortunately not specific to server side Blazor over .NET 6 - does not display the real exception and I keep getting that warning.

Does IIS need any further permissions beyond username and password to access the SQL Server database from a Blazor server side app?

How can I temporarily set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to "development" for production environment on a .NET 6 Blazor Server side app?

Comment: Why not log the actual exception somewhere? If it's "hanging" for some period of time then that sounds like some kind of timeout, like a lack of connectivity. If it was a permission issue there'd be no delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To temporarily display errors in production, you can add this line to the `<PropertyGroup>` of your main project file:

```
<EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
```

But be aware that your production environment will then pick up settings defined in the appsettings.Development.json file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Finally discovered the problem was Blazor trying to access SQL from same server with a subdomain sql.[mydomain].com as Datasource.
Developer environment could access it from the internet, but in order to access it locally I've had to add an entry 127.0.0.1 sql.[mydomain].com to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host

Anyway if anybody has any solution to temporarily display errors on production it will be apreciated